# Blazor MudSelect @bind-SelectedValues to a dictionary

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I need to bind @bind-SelectedValues to the values in a ductionary.
But it gives a
CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<System.Collections.Generic.List>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'

```
<MudTable Items="users.UserList" Loading="@_loading" LoadingProgressColor="Color.Info">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>User</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Applications</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Edit</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="User">@context.FullName</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Application">
            <MudSelect Variant="Variant.Outlined" T="int" Label="Applications" MultiSelection="true" 
                @bind-Value="value" 
                @bind-SelectedValues="userAppsDict[context.Id]">
                @foreach(var item in apps.ApplicationList)
                {
                    <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="@item.Id">@item.Name</MudSelectItem>
                }
            </MudSelect>
        </MudTd>
        <MudTd>
            <MudButton Color="Color.Primary" Variant="Variant.Filled">Update</MudButton>
        </MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>

@code{
    [Inject]
    private IApplicationService service{ get; set; }
    private int value { get; set; }
    private IEnumerable<int> options { get; set; } = new HashSet<int>();
    private bool _loading = false;
    private Dictionary<int, List<int>> userAppsDict { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

    UserHasApplicationsReadViewModel userApps = new UserHasApplicationsReadViewModel();
    UserReadViewModel users = new UserReadViewModel();
    ApplicationReadViewModel apps = new ApplicationReadViewModel();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _loading = true;
        userApps = await service.GetUserHasApplications();
        users = await service.GetUsers();
        apps = await service.GetApplicationsAsync();

        foreach(var user in users.UserList)
        {
            List<int> appIdList = new List<int>();
            var appsbyUid = await service.GetApplicationByUserId(user.Id);
            foreach (var item in appsbyUid.ApplicationList)
            {
                appIdList.Add(item.Id);
            }
            userAppsDict.Add(user.Id, appIdList);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(userAppsDict));
        _loading = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to bind @bind-SelectedValues to the values in a ductionary

Need is a subjective term.. MB wants to put a hashset of strings into the SelectedValues bind, so the path of least resistance is to let it, and then back-translate that, perhaps like this:

```
@inject ISnackbar Snackbar

<MudTable Items="users" Loading="@_loading" LoadingProgressColor="Color.Info">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>User</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Applications</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Edit</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="User">@context.FullName</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Application">
            <MudSelect Variant="Variant.Outlined" Label="Applications" MultiSelection="true" 
                @bind-SelectedValues="context.Apps">
                @foreach(var item in apps)
                {
                    <MudSelectItem Value="@item.Name">@item.Name</MudSelectItem>
                }
            </MudSelect>
        </MudTd>
        <MudTd>
            <MudButton Color="Color.Primary" Variant="Variant.Filled"  OnClick="@(() => UpdateUser(context))">Update</MudButton>
        </MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>


@code{
    private bool _loading = false;

    List<User> users = new List<User>();
    List<App> apps = new List<App>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _loading = true;
        apps = new List<App>{ 
            new(){
                Id = 1,
                Name = "FirstApp"
            },
            new(){
                Id = 2,
                Name = "SecondApp"
            }
        };
        users = new List<User>{
            new User{ 
                Id = 1,
                FullName = "Firstappuser",
                Apps = new HashSet<string>{ apps.First().Name }
            },
            new User{ 
                Id = 2,
                FullName = "Secondappuser",
                Apps = new HashSet<string>{ apps.Last().Name }
            },
            
        };
        _loading = false;
    }

    class User{
      public int Id {get;set;}
      public string FullName {get;set;}
      public IEnumerable<string> Apps {get;set;}
    }
    class App{
      public int Id {get;set;}
      public string Name {get;set;}
    }

    void UpdateUser(User u){
      var newApps = u.Apps.Select(a => apps.First(app => app.Name == a)).ToArray();
      Snackbar.Add("Updating user " + u.FullName + " to have apps " + string.Join(",", newApps.Select(app => app.Id.ToString())));
    }
}
```

I had to invent classes to cover the use case, but it also highlights you *don't* have to use the classes you're given as models; feel free to do whatever is necessary to model things simply. Here each User has a `IEnumerable<string>` that will track the apps a user has, not a `Dictionary<userid, List<app ids>>` so the 1:M User:App association is *inside each user*.. When the update button is clicked the user is passed to the handler, and there's a process to reverse the app names back into apps (the `newApps` line then I stringJoin their IDs into a snackbar to prove it was able to reverse the app names to apps, and get the IDs instead

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cEQGkmwGgvbuyXTd